# ip link add fails when run in a script

Tags: bash, docker, iproute

I have docker container where I need some dummy interfaces. It is based on Ubuntu 16.04 and it has the `NET_ADMIN` capability.
The following command works

```
# ip link add dum0 type dummy
```

However, when running this from a .sh script I get the following error:

```
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported
```

What am I missing?